# Angularjs using angularui in a directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to make my first angularjs app and I have run into some trouble. I'm trying to include and use angular's ui-bootstrap. I need a progress bar inside a template/directive I have made but I can't seem to get it to work.

I can get the progress bar inside of index.html to show up. However the ones inside the stats.html does not. I'm pretty sure I need to tell the directive I made to use ui-bootstrap but I am not sure how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

app.js

```
'use strict';
var player = {
  stats: {
    str: 10,
    int: 15,
    spd: 18
  }
}

var monster = {
  stats: {
    str: 20,
    int: 25,
    spd: 28
  }
}
// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
var app = angular.module('stabber', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
app.directive('statBlock',function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: false,
        templateUrl: 'wigets/stats.html'
      }
});
app.controller('playerStats', function($scope) {
  $scope.stats=player.stats;
});

app.controller('monsterStats', function($scope) {
  $scope.stats=monster.stats;
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>My AngularJS App</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body ng-app="stabber">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 statblock"  ng-controller="playerStats">
                <stat-block></stat-block>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
Picture stuff here <uib-progressbar value="55"></uib-progressbar>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 statblock"  ng-controller="monsterStats">
                <stat-block></stat-block>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

stats.html

```
<table border="1">
    <th colspan="2" >STATS</th>
    <tr>
        <td>STR: {{stats.str}}</td>
        <td>HP</td>
        <td><uib-progressbar value="55"></uib-progressbar></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>INT: {{stats.int}}</td>
        <td>MP</td>
        <td><uib-progressbar value="55"></uib-progressbar></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>SPD: {{stats.spd}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your progress bar is there, you just need to give your td a width.

Comment: *facepalm* So focused on learning Angular I forgot my html :)